# Application path location in MS windows

Tags: c++, windows, path

Where should I store the application installation folder for application to reffer ?

Comment: Your application implicitly knows where it's launched from. Just use relative paths to access your application resources and then your users can have multiple installations without them screwing each other up.

Comment: Hi Anon, 
Say the application is not launched from its installation folder and by another application which doesnot know how to communicate with my application. In that cage GetCurrentDirectory() call gives me the path of launching application and not my application. What should I do in that case ? 
Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're looking for is the [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28VS.85%29.aspx) function, which you can use like so:

```
// get the full path to the current executable
wchar_t fullPath[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, fullPath, MAX_PATH);

// cut the string at the last slash, because we just want the directory
// not the actual executeable file name. 
TCHAR *lastSlash = wcsrchr(fullPath, L'\\');
lastSlash = 0;

// directory where the executable is location is fullPath
```

This will work regardless of the current working directory and in general, this is how I do *all* "relative path" stuff (that is, I never actually use relative paths, they're always absolute paths, based off the value returned from the function above).

Comment: Note that this is where you were launched from, not where your app was installed to. They _should_ of course be the same...

Comment: +1 for using the Unicode functions. But it must be `*lastSlash = 0`, and you should test whether the search for the slash was successful. Also consider using a `wstring` object instead of the C array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the registry for storing installation folders.

Answer (score 0):

::GetModuleFileName(NULL, out_lpPathName, in_size) will give you full path of your executable file.

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationData folder, even not admin access can help to access you install data. use *SHGetSpecialFolderPath* with CISDL **CSIDL_APPDATA**

Answer (score 0):

In the registry. To be specific, under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\YourCompanyName\YourApplicationName\` if you installed your app for all users (i.e. in \Program Files), and under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\YourCompanyName\YourApplicationName\` if you installed it for a single user only.